# What time will overwatch update?

Tags: overwatch

What time will Overwatch update today? Contemplating whether I should attain last second Halloween loot boxes.

Comment: We have no way of knowing this, we aren't Blizzard...

Comment: @Kaizerwolf Blizzard always does their patch on the same weekday, same hour. Plus, it will give a place to duplicate other thread like this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm used to see patches from Blizzard hit at 7AM PST or 10AM EST. I don't think it would be anything different today.

Unless they announce an increased time on the event on facebook / twitter. But one hour from patch time, it's VERY unlikely.